# Instance not storing in array. What do I have wrong here?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am having issues trying to get this program to run, the applet loads,  but when I enter a number and click ok,  nothing seems to happen...  I am not sure if I have an issue with the array or where my issue might lie.

I can't seem to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



    public class LargestApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int number =0;
        double highNumber=-1;
        double lowNumber=-1;



        // Create components for applet
        Label numberLabel = new Label("Enter a number:");
        TextField numberField = new TextField(5);
        Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");

        Label highNumberOutputLabel = new Label("The Highest number is: 0         ");

        public void init() {
            add(numberLabel);
            add(numberField);
            numberField.requestFocus();
            add(okButton);
            add(cancelButton);
            add(highNumberOutputLabel);
            setSize(400, 500);  // Sets the size of the applet window
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int number = 0, highNumber = -1;

            if (numberField.getText().length() == 0) {
                numberField.requestFocus();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Number Cannot blank", "D A T A   E R R O R",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            try {
                number = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                numberField.requestFocus();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number is invalid",
                        "D A T A   E R R O R", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            if (number < 0 || number > 10) {
                numberField.requestFocus();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Number must be between 0 and 10",
                        "D A T A   E R R O R", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            // Determine highest number
            Integer [] numberAr = {number};
            for(int i = 0; i < numberAr.length; i++)
            {
                number += numberAr[i];
                if (numberAr[i] < lowNumber)
                    lowNumber = numberAr[i];
                else if (numberAr[i] > highNumber)
                    highNumber = numberAr[i];
            }

            // Display the results
            highNumberOutputLabel.setText("The Highest Number is:   "
                    + (highNumber));




}
        }
```

Comment: **Again** as per you previous question, look at the line that is throwing the exception. So which line is causing the NPE to be thrown? Which line is line 40 of your class above?

Comment: I was able to fix the ERROR,  The program loads just fine now,  without errors.  It just is not storing any instances of the inputs

Comment: @bfr So, just be clear, you *are* or *are not* getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: I am not getting a null pointer

Comment: @bfr Then please remove it from your question

Comment: I am sorry about that,  I failed to post with the Null pointer, that was my mistake,  please forgive me.

Comment: @bfr Thanks, much clearer now

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding the ActionListener to your buttons, and so pushing a button will have no effect. Fix that by calling `addActionListener(this)` on the relevant Button. Just having your GUI class extend ActionListener (which is also not a good idea in general) does not magically give buttons the action listener code, and pressing a button will have no effect if you don't first give it code to have a behavior.

More importantly, you should be coding with Swing (JApplet, JButton) not AWT. While Swing is admittedly out of date, AWT is prehistoric in comparison.

And most importantly for us, you should not be posting NullPointerExceptions with your question if you code isn't throwing any.

Comment: I spent a good couple of minutes trying to figure out where the seemingly impossible null pointer exception was coming from, this does not endear you to me @bfr

Comment: I am sorry,  I failed to remove the Null pointer,  that was my mistake,  I removed them.

Comment: @bfr: thank you for removing it. Down-vote removed, and up-vote instated. It made it quite hard to figure out what was wrong. Do you understand my answer?

Comment: I am not sure where I am supposed to add the addActionListener(this),  can you give me an idea?

Comment: @bfr: You add it to the button variables. Have you gone through a tutorial yet? Have you gone through the basic Java tutorials? You'll want to do that first. And you still haven't addressed the issue of why you're coding with AWT and not Swing. You'll find Swing more powerful and flexible with better tutorials, and you'll also find a lot more Swing expertise on this and other sites than AWT, so you'll be able to get better help for Swing GUIs.